# Bucket not found error in lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am using a cloudformation template that I found here and it is working as expected...

https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/ai-driven-social-media-dashboard/

It has a following section where the lambda function code is defined.

```
Mappings:
  Function:
    SocialMediaMLFunction:
      S3Bucket: solutions
      S3Key: ai-driven-social-media-dashboard/v1.0.0/socialmediafunction.zip
    AddTriggerForFunction:
      S3Bucket: solutions
      S3Key: ai-driven-social-media-dashboard/v1.0.0/addtriggerfunction.zip
  Code:
    EC2Twitter:
      S3Bucket: solutions
      S3Key: ai-driven-social-media-dashboard/v1.0.0/ec2_twitter_reader.tar
```

As soon as I change the S3Bucket location from "solutions" to something else, I get an error.

> The specified bucket does not exist

How do I point the mapping to my own S3 file location? Does the bucket needs special privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be changing them, as these are buckets and objects hosted by AWS for this template.

If you want to host the lambda code yourself, the instructions on how to do it are given in the solution's github page in [Building Lambda Package](https://github.com/amazon-archives/ai-driven-social-media-dashboard#building-lambda-package).